# Firebase Reset Password

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

The documentation does not provide any information on how or event if it's possible to change the users' password from an app.

We are currently sending an e-mail to the users which opens a Firebase page but it does not enforce password complexity.

We would like to have a screen where user would be able to reset their password.

In the FirebaseAuth.framework there is this method:

```
/** @fn confirmPasswordResetWithCode:newPassword:completion:
@brief Resets the password given a code sent to the user outside of the app and a new password
  for the user.

@param newPassword The new password.
@param completion Optionally; a block which is invoked when the request finishes. Invoked
    asynchronously on the main thread in the future.

@remarks Possible error codes:

    + `FIRAuthErrorCodeWeakPassword` - Indicates an attempt to set a password that is
        considered too weak.
    + `FIRAuthErrorCodeOperationNotAllowed` - Indicates the administrator disabled sign
        in with the specified identity provider.
    + `FIRAuthErrorCodeExpiredActionCode` - Indicates the OOB code is expired.
    + `FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidActionCode` - Indicates the OOB code is invalid.

@remarks See `FIRAuthErrors` for a list of error codes that are common to all API methods.
**/
- (void)confirmPasswordResetWithCode:(NSString *)code
                     newPassword:(NSString *)newPassword
                      completion:(FIRConfirmPasswordResetCallback)completion;
```

And other method to verify that code:

```
/** @fn verifyPasswordResetCode:completion:
@brief Checks the validity of a verify password reset code.

@param code The password reset code to be verified.
@param completion Optionally; a block which is invoked when the request finishes. Invoked
    asynchronously on the main thread in the future.
*/
- (void)verifyPasswordResetCode:(NSString *)code
                 completion:(FIRVerifyPasswordResetCodeCallback)completion;
```

But there does not seem to be a way to generate that code in Swift neither from the Firebase Console.
The code seem to be provided in the email template `%LINK%` but it does not say if it's possible to provide only the code.

So my question is, is there any way to have a reset password screen in a mobile app, preferably in an iOS app ? And if So, How do I send that code to the users?

Comment: You can easily either construct your own [password reset landing page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) or even have the [password reset link redirect back to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions).

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: password) { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

for a currently logged in User.

Comment: Hi, the idea is to reset the password of non logged in user

Comment: Well then you have to use a third party like email, otherwise if they could do it in app without being authenticated you dont need security

Comment: If you want to be able to do it in app, why don't you just use phone number identification ? Or authenticate the phone number and then request a new password within the app following your rules ?

Comment: Mark, The idea would be like for Cognito, the email sent by Firebase would contain a code instead of a link, and the user would input the code and then the new password.

Comment: Firebase Supports Email, Password-less login, if thats what you want. If you want a login feature that isn't supported, then you probably have the wrong product !

Comment: I built a reset password form where the user types in their email.  That works find and sends it to the function but the function fails.  The user isn't logged in, so I need to use firebases resetpassword event.